# JSQuery - how to use jquery for a beginner

Tags: jquery

Hi I am not familiar with jquery at all. but i want to have a dock style menu in a website i am trying to learn and make. 
the dock style menu example at 
http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/examples/example.php?f=lh_edge
it gives you options to copy html, css, javasript codes.
on a different page which actually the source page for this example there is an option to download script.

i need to have three of these dock style menu 
1. top horizontal menu (not exactly at top but say about at 1/5th of the page height. 
2. this vertical menu (as in example).
3. at the bottom of the page.
of course i will have my own images to replace these icon images.

So will somebody be kind enough to guide me to right direction (as i am a totally stanger to all this so i'd prefer the easiest way possible)

Comment: Start with [How jQuery Works](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) and [the rest of the tutorials...](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the jQuery Slide functions, it seems to be the basis of the menu that you link to:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

Here is an example to experiment with:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

Answer (score 0):

Putting it very simply, you need a div element which contains a list of images that you want to show in the menu. In the document load event, you would

```
$(function() {
    var opts = {
        align: 'top',
        // all the required options
    };
    $("#div-id").jqDock(opts);
});
```

Call the jqDock method on all the 3 div (using the id that you give to the div) with the options that you want.

You can set the options object when calling the jqDock() function on the div to set up if it should come horizontal or vertical. You can find details of the various other options here - http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/index.php?dt=0&pg=options

align : string, default = 'bottom', values = 'top', 'middle', 'bottom', left', center', 'right'
Fixes the horizontal/vertical main axis, and direction of expansion.

For a horizontal menu:
'top' : fixes the top edge of the dock, so that images expand down
'middle' : fixes the middle of the images, so that images expand up and down equally
'bottom' : fixes the bottom edge of the dock, so that images expand up
For a vertical menu:
'left' : fixes the left edge of the dock, so that images expand right
'center' : fixes the center of the images, so that images expand left and right equally
'right' : fixes the right edge of the dock, so that images expand left